# What is the equivalent of Master Page and Web User Control in PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net

Assume that I have some advertisments that I want to put in specific area of my pages. In ASP.NET I would use Web User Control for this pupose. What about in PHP? The same question for Master Page.

Answer (score 6):

The "master page" and "web user control" are classes that are specifically provided by the ASP.NET framework. Just as these capabilities are not native to the languages of Visual Basic or C#, neither are they native to language of PHP - they must implemented on a framework level.

You could certainly do it yourself, however if you're looking for an ASP.NET-like experience in PHP then I suggest you look at [the Prado framework](http://www.pradosoft.com/), which is very similar and implements many of the features that you've probably used.

Comment: This is the answer to your questions.  There is no language-specific counter part to MasterPages.  However, you can use includes to give you a semi-similar experience of Web User Controls

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concepts in PHP. I think that it may have some frameworks that implement it, but I don't know wich. Or you can code it by your own :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do it by putting them in include tags or required

e.g:

```
<?php

 include ('global/header.php');

 //Main content goes here

 include ('global/main-right.php'); //Adverts or such
 include ('global/footer.php');
 ?>
```

Where global is a folder containing files used on several pages

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing similar, but you can implement such feature yourself, create header, footer, sidebar and... pages and in other pages include them.

Answer (score 0):

One PHP project that does this well is PPI.

Here is an example of your "master template" which is has historically been named template.php

Folder: https://github.com/dragoonis/ppi-skeleton-app/tree/master/App/View/default/

File: https://github.com/dragoonis/ppi-skeleton-app/tree/master/App/View/default/template.php

If you look at line 28 you'll see the footer content. So say you wanted your widget/"web user control" to be in the footer then you can simply add

```
    include($viewDir . 'controls/footer_control.php');
```

It's that simple, and will be included in every page load.

Good luck with your search,

Regards,
Paul Dragoonis.